# Cookies contador de visitas en PHP

Tags: php, cookies

estoy realizando un pequeño código en PHP para crear una cookie que sirva para ver si es la primera vez que entra en una pagina o cual es su numero de visita. Me salta un mensaje de que la variable no esta declarada, no se muy bien como funciona esto de las cookies ya que no lo han explicado adecuadamente.

Código:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['visitas']))
    {
        setcookie('visitas',$visitas+1,time()+3600*24);
        $mensaje = 'Numero de visitas: '.$_COOKIE['visitas'];   
    }
    else
    {
        setcookie('visitas',1,time()+3600*24);
        $mensaje = 'Bienvenido por primera vez a nuesta web';
    }

?>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php $mensaje;?>
        </p>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia la variable `$visitas` por `$_COOKIE['visitas']`:

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ] ) ) {

    setcookie( 'visitas', $_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ] + 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
    $mensaje = 'Numero de visitas: '.$_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ];
}
else {

    setcookie( 'visitas', 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
    $mensaje = 'Bienvenido por primera vez a nuesta web';
}
```

Comment: Ahora no me salta ningún error de que la variable no esta declarada, pero ahora no me muestra ningún mensaje

Comment: @MarioGuiber - porque te falta `echo` aquí `<?php echo $mensaje;?>`

Comment: Exacto ahora mismo lo iba a rectificar

Comment: Gracias @aldanux :)

Comment: @MarioGuiber - Un placer... ;)